# How does one prove the equivalence of two types and that a signature is singly-inhabited?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-theory

Anyone who has been following [Tony Morris' blog](http://blog.tmorris.net/) and scala exercises, will know that these two type signatures are equivalent:

```
trait MyOption1[A] {
  //this is a catamorphism
  def fold[B](some : A => B, none : => B) : B 
}
```

And:

```
trait MyOption2[A] {
  def map[B](f : A => B) : MyOption2[B]
  def getOrElse[B >: A](none : => B) : B
}
```

Furthermore, it has been stated that the type is *singly-inhabited* (i.e. all implementations of the type are exactly equivalent). I can guess at proving the equivalence of the two types but don't really know where to start on the single-inhabitance statement. How does one prove this?

Comment: cstheory.stackexchange.com might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 2):

The `Option` type is doubly-inhabited. It can either contain something or not. This is clear from the signature of `fold` in the first trait, in which you can only:

- return the result of applying `some`, if you have a value of type `A` sitting around (you're a `Some`)
- return your `none` argument (you're a `None`)

Any given implementation can only do one or the other, without violating referential transparency.

So I believe it's a mistake to call it singly-inhabited. But any implementation of either of these traits must be isomorphic to one of these two cases.

#### EDIT

That said, I don't think you can really characterize the "inhabitedness" of a type without knowing its constructors. If you were to extend one of these option traits with an implementation that had a constructor which took a `Tuple12[A]`, for instance, you could write 13 different versions of `fold`.